# How put two element close css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to take two element and close their, one near the other. I need to do this with CSS so  This is my html code:

```
<section class="vc_row section-wrapper vc_custom_1453226174905 vc_row-has-fill">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6 vc_col-md-4">
        <div class="vc_column-inner ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper"> 

            <div class="spotlight-wrap spotlight-default ">

              <figure class="tt-effect">

                <img src="http://andrejceccoli.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/programmaPolitico.jpg" alt="Programma Elettorale">

                <figcaption>
                  <h2>Programma Elettorale</h2>        
                    <div class="content">
                      <p>Tutti i punti del mostro programma elettorale.</p>
                      <a class="btn btn-outline " href="http://andrejceccoli.com/?page_id=15" title="">Leggi di più</a>
                    </div>
                </figcaption>
              </figure>
            </div> <!-- spotlight-wrap -->
```

//Anyone can help me?

```
          //NEW FIGURE
              <figure class="tt-effect">
                <img src="http://trendytheme.net/demo2/wp/nominee/onepage/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Issues-one-page-360x250.jpg" alt="Issues">
                <figcaption>
                  <h2>Issues</h2>                  
                  <div class="content">
                    <p>Rapidiously integrate plug-and-play channels rather than cost effective ideas.</p>

                    <a class="btn btn-outline " href="http://trendytheme.net/demo2/wp/nominee/onepage/issue-right-sidebar/" title="">Learn more</a>
                  </div>
                </figcaption>    
              </figure>
            </div> <!-- spotlight-wrap -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How can I do this? with a css?

Comment: have you tried anything? which two elements need to be close to each other

Comment: I try "display: inline-block;" but it doesn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Just add CSS style to `figure` tag:

```
figure {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

```css
figure {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="vc_row section-wrapper vc_custom_1453226174905 vc_row-has-fill">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6 vc_col-md-4">
        <div class="vc_column-inner ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper"> 

           <figure class="tt-effect">
                <img src="http://andrejceccoli.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/programmaPolitico.jpg" alt="Programma Elettorale">
                <figcaption>
                  <h2>Programma Elettorale</h2>        
                    <div class="content">
                      <p>Tutti i punti del mostro programma elettorale.</p>
                      <a class="btn btn-outline " href="http://andrejceccoli.com/?page_id=15" title="">Leggi di più</a>
                    </div>
                </figcaption>
              </figure>

              <figure class="tt-effect">
                <img src="http://trendytheme.net/demo2/wp/nominee/onepage/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Issues-one-page-360x250.jpg" alt="Issues">
                <figcaption>
                  <h2>Issues</h2>                  
                  <div class="content">
                    <p>Rapidiously integrate plug-and-play channels rather than cost effective ideas.</p>

                    <a class="btn btn-outline " href="http://trendytheme.net/demo2/wp/nominee/onepage/issue-right-sidebar/" title="">Learn more</a>
                  </div>
                </figcaption>    
              </figure>

            </div> <!-- spotlight-wrap -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `float: left;`. Otherwise, it would be good to give more informations. For example, which elements need to be close to each other.

Ah, if you use float, make the next element `clear: both;`. Otherwise your design could be destroyed.